# Bootstrap in React Navbar Toggle Background Not Working

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm having issues with a Bootstrap navbar using React. It was working perfectly, but unexpectedly, the background of my Navbar is no longer visible when I expand the dropdown menu. In other words, it doesn't drop down and cover all the options of the Navbar. Additionally, when I click on the dropdown menu, the Navbar moves up and loses its initial aligned position.

I tried bringing in a new navbar, but the same issue persists.
I also tried "commenting out" the entire project except for the new Navbar, but it still doesn't work.

In the console, I'm receiving the following warning:

Compiled with warnings.

```
Warning
(345:5) autoprefixer: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead

Warning
(346:5) autoprefixer: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

WARNING in ./src/css/styles.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/css/styles.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(345:5) autoprefixer: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead

WARNING in ./src/css/styles.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/css/styles.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(346:5) autoprefixer: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead

webpack compiled with 2 warnings
```

HELP
Thank you very much!

I tried changing de code and adding new components